# Split array into pairs of varying depth

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion, optimization

Let there is an array `a[0],a[1],..,a[6]`. I want to implement an algorithm that will return all sorts of various amounts of depth. To make it more understandable, consider what i have to return the algorithm for different values of the depth

```
depth: 1, 
return: 
       (a[6] - a[0]); /*the only possible case for depth = 1*/

depth: 2, 
return: 
       (a[1] - a[0]) + (a[6] - a[2]); /*first case*/
       (a[2] - a[0]) + (a[6] - a[3]); /*second case*/
       (a[3] - a[0]) + (a[6] - a[4]); /*third case*/
       (a[4] - a[0]) + (a[6] - a[5]); /*fourth*/

depth: 3,
return:
       (a[1] - a[0]) + (a[3] - a[2]) + (a[6] - a[4]); /*first case*/
       (a[1] - a[0]) + (a[4] - a[2]) + (a[6] - a[5]); /*second case*/
       (a[2] - a[0]) + (a[4] - a[3]) + (a[6] - a[5]); /*third case*/
```

It was an example for array of length `7`. I want the algorithm worked for an array of arbitrary length.

I was able to implement the algorithm using recursion. The following is the code in C++

```
int arr[101]; /*Original array with length N = 100*/
set <__int64> Partitions; /*Set, for accumulation of the sum of the partitions*/

void get_partitions(int start, int end, int depth, int sum) {
    if (depth == 1) {
        sum += (arr[end] - arr[start]);

        Partitions.insert(sum);
    }
    else {
        int k = end - 2 * (depth - 1);
        int new_start = start + 1;

        while (new_start <= k) {
            int current_sum = (arr[new_start] - arr[new_start - 1]);

            get_partitions((new_start + 1), end, (depth - 1), (sum + current_sum));

            new_start++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    get_partitions(0, 100, 5, 0);

    //processing of Partitions

    return 0;
}
```

This implementation has problem of work. For an array of large dimension, program execution time is too long.

Is it possible to improve the algorithm? Are there any other implementations of this algorithm? I would be grateful for answers.

Comment: Unclear for me what your algorithm is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is what I meant. I apologize for the mistake. Question text fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> initialize(std::size_t depth)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> res(depth - 1);

    int i = 1;
    for (auto& e : res) {
        e = i;
        i += 2;
    }
    return res;
}

bool increase(std::vector<std::size_t>& indexes, std::size_t max)
{
    auto m = max;
    auto rit = indexes.rbegin();
    for (; rit != indexes.rend(); ++rit) {
        ++*rit;
        if (*rit + 1 != m) {
            m = *rit;
            for (auto it = rit.base(); it != indexes.end(); ++it) {
                *it = m + 2;
                m += 2;
            }
            if (m < max) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        m = *rit - 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/enLfM1).